# Imported object cannot have texture mapped

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

[image: sword with texture]

[image: shield with texture]

So my sword and shield has texture mapped, but my soldier do not have texture mapped onto it. May I know what's the reason and why?

Comment: You have 3 assigned materials on that model, what are the first 2? Material #0 and 01 - default? What happens if you change their colors?

Comment: oohh I see, the other 2 material node is mapped to the solder surface, thanks for the hint. I am so noob :( you just saved my day

Comment: No worry, 1 object can have multiple different materials that all use different settings, You can select some faces in edit mode, pick one of the materials and press Assign to assign that specific face to selected material